# Grails 3.x modify mavenLocal() to direct to another location and name other than the default one

Tags: maven, grails, gradle, grails-3.0

I am trying to run a Grails 3.0.6 application on a VMware VDI (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure). I would like to direct my Maven local repository to a location other than `<Username>/.m2/repository`

How should I do it?
VDI is a painful environment for developers but I have been tasked to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Grails 3.x uses Gradle you can easily define this in your `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        // mavenLocal()
        maven { url "file://<your path here>" } // this one does the job
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
    }
}
```